# Is it correct to use plural, then define it in singular form?

Tags: grammatical-number, agreement

For example:

> Snow leopards, another mammal with a relatively large tail, are also known to [...]

Edit: changed from *big cat* to *mammal* to emphasise that it's a definition, not a noun.

Comment: No. That looks wrong. I don't know what you are trying to do. Are you giving a series of definitions? What came before this?

Comment: Try "The snow leopard, another big cat . . ."

Comment: Thanks. Before I write about how few large animals have proportionately large tails (compared to small animals), however cheetahs are thought to use their large tails for maneuverability. So I want to mention that snow-leopards also have relatively large tails compared to other big cats (big cats being a classification of felids including lions, tigers etc.)

Comment: [*Wombats are a native marsupial mammal,*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=hxcTVuaaKYSh8wfP6ry4Ag&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Wombats+are+a+native+marsupial+mammal%2C%22) and I have no problem with that. Perhaps because another likely word there would be ***species***, in which case no-one could say for sure whether you actually *meant* it to be understood as a plural. But I bet if you asked people to paraphrase by substituting some semantically-equivalent text for ***species*** in such a context, they'd always produce a singular form, not remove the ***a***.

Comment: It sounds cleaner if introduced in the singular.  Saying it as "The snow leopard, another mammal with a relatively large tail, are also known ton [...]" sounds cleaner.  When I think big tail, I think of T-rex, Alligators, and Kangaroos.  Compared to them the snow leopard has a long skinny tail.

Comment: @EngrStudent: no that's not cleaner because you've introduced a number disagreement "The snow leopard are..." ("are" should be changed to "Is").

Comment: @mgkrebbs - you are exactly right.  Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1):

I would clarify what the snow leopard is being compared to (you said, "another mammal with a relatively large tail"). The sentence by itself does not make very much sense. It would be helpful if you could include some context.